# Is the pair tenant/host correct?

Tags: word-usage, collocations

Question from non-native English speaker.
I am building a website where users would be able to list their property for the long term rent. I need names for both types of users. I know that Tenant can have Landlord and vice versa, but some people considers the word "Landlord" being offensive, so I wanted to use word Host instead.

Question is whether it is correct in English to pair word "tenant" with the word "host" (like the obvious pair of guest/host)

If no, is the pair guest/host good for long term rent?

If no, please suggest some better pairs, without using the word "Landlord"

Comment: In what context is landlord offensive? Is it offensive in specific regions? If so, you could use homeowner/renter as a pair. As a landlord, I generally use this pair when explaining my relationship to the person renting my house.

Comment: For me it is not offensive. Some people are asking this question https://www.quora.com/Is-the-term-Landlord-considered-offensive-these-days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is something of a frame challege)

I assume it is because "landlord" is gendered that you think it might be offensive. I think you are being hypersensitive. "Landlord" is the usual term, regardless of gender. See for example "[Openrent.co.uk](https://www.openrent.co.uk/)" It uses the terms "tenant" and "landlord".

Airbnb uses "guests" and "hosts" because their model is one of short stay, often with the host staying in the house. That is quite different to your model.

Therefore the proper term to use is "Landlord".  This is not considered "offensive".

Comment: For me its not offensive. For some people it is offensive because they ask this question https://www.quora.com/Is-the-term-Landlord-considered-offensive-these-days . Ultimately, if native English speakers do not consider it offensive (at least majority), I'll probably use it

Comment: That question has three answers:  "no it's not offensive",  "of course not" and "In Pennsylvania, you must use landlord".

Comment: Excuse me, you guys but there is also landlady. In fact. But in many leases landlord is used.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think '**host** and **guest**' works because a guest does not always pay.

A pair of words describing the two parties can be '**letter** and **renter**'.

Please see [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/letter) for

> **letter**: one that rents or leases.

and their [entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/renter) for

> **renter**: one that rents
> *specifically*: the lessee or tenant of property.

Answer (score 1):

- lessor [the owner or landlord] and the lessee [the one who gets the apartment], That's contractual language. So not great here.
- renters and apartment owners/rental agents

The word host does not work here at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use 'renter' and 'property manager'.

Comment: A property manager is something different to a landlord.  The landlord owns the property.  The property manager is paid by the landlord to look after the property. Sometimes landlords will manage their own properties, but not always.